# How to do the template matching in real time

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, templates

I'm new to OpenCV. I'm trying to do the template matching in real time. But it seems the program I did is not functional as I expected. I coded the program as follow.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

template = cv2.imread('scratch_test.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    if gray.shape[0]>template.shape[0] and gray.shape[1]>template.shape[1]:
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        threshold = 0.8
        loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cv2.rectangle(frame, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
        cv2.imshow('orginal', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        print "Error : Template and image size are: ", template.shape, gray.shape
```

How can I solve this problem

Comment: Have you made sure that you are successfully reading from the webcam?

Comment: Your template image should not be greater than your input image. Keep in mind that `matchTemplate` is **not** invariant to _affine transformations_.

Comment: @JackGold Yes I can read from the camera

Comment: @ElouarnLaine In this case, my input is video stream, how can I find the size of video stream?

Comment: Is your `template` also gray?

Comment: @ElouarnLaine and the size of image has no issue when I just try to match two images without camera

Comment: @Rick M No? I think only the video frame is gray

Comment: I am not sure about this but shouldn't both be in the same color space? If not, the main image should be color and the template can be gray but not the other way around.

Comment: Actually `matchTemplate` is only _invariant to translations_. So, yes, the size of the images does matter (template and input images) if you want the function to find a match.

Comment: @RickM Yes, I solved the size problem. But the program cannot find the target picture in real time.

Comment: @ElouarnLaine Yes, I solved the size problem. But the program cannot find the target picture in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add sanity check before calling `res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)` just in case if the camera returned an empty frame or if the frame resolution is less than the template size:

```
if gray.shape[0]>template.shape[0] and gray.shape[1]>template.shape[1]:
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
else:
    print "Error : Template and image size are: ", template.shape, gray.shape
```

Comment: But it would prevent the app from crashing and OP would be able to debug, where exactly is the problem, I will improve my answer with time as per the further issues faced by OP

Comment: Yeah, now the program works. But it seems it cannot detect the target image, is there anything else I missed?

Comment: @Darren ZdaR 's answer is not a fix for your problem; It will only help you pointing out one of the issues you have. Can you tell us if ZdaR 's error message (_"Error : Template and image size are: "_) is being printed out?

Comment: @ElouarnLaine, Yeah. I changed my template size, and now the error was gone. But I still cannot detect the target image. What can I do now

Comment: @Darren Can you upload the sample template image and sample video input frame ? You may need to change the threshold to a lower value and see if template gets detected ?